# Как в SQL таблице изменить все записи с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Суть проблемы: в sql-таблице есть поле, в котором лежат числа вида `1,5` (в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части стоит **запятая**), но тип поля **VARCHAR**

Вопрос: как можно в определенном поле БД заменить во всех записях `,` на `.` одним запросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все значения поля в одном формате, то регулярное выражение не нужно, достаточно простой замены подстрок. Для этого используйте функцию **`REPLACE`**:

```
UPDATE somevalue
SET somevalue = REPLACE(somevalue, ',', '.')
```

Здесь [документация функции](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: Ага, то что нужно, я может быть и сам бы разобрался, но даже не знаю как гуглить такой вопрос...

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев на английском материалов полно. Для этого вопроса можно легко найти ответ загуглив `"mysql update string field"`.